# How would I go about adding tabs to partition blog posts in an MVC application?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Alright, so let me elaborate since I'm not totally sure how to ask this question (perhaps why I have found nothing to help me). When I am adding posts to my website, I want to be able to say "Alright, that's ten posts, time to start a new tab". These tabs are what you typically see on a website when there are multiple pages of content. I am using C# with the MVC framework and my content is being stored in a localDB, it is currently being loaded by going through the model and displaying each item in the model. Side note, if my terminology sounds off or whatever, that's because I've only used C# for about a month now (my background is C) so my apologies for that. I just feel like it's such a common feature that it can't be that massively complex to do, I'm just not totally sure how to do it...

I'll quickly list a few of the things I have tried, I thought to myself if I can figure out how many rows there are in the database, divide that by how many articles I want to display per page, that will give me the tab count, which I could then say alright, once you've displayed this many articles, create a tab and continue where you left off. I tried and failed due to a lack of knowledge (I don't know where to look for something so specific). I tried other minor things but quickly realized they would not work. I'm not sure what code people would want to see (I'm assuming it's more just here's what we typically do) so if any code is needed I'm more than happy to post it.

Thanks so much in advance, typically I don't go online asking for help (This is my first time asking for help ever actually) but I am really just stumped on this.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing [pagination](http://alloyui.com/examples/pagination/real-world/). It's a very broad question though.

Comment: I figured it was a broad topic, but hey that at least gives me something to look into, thanks man!

Comment: If you don't know HTML, then ASP.NET MVC is not going to help you. There's no "Tab control". You first have to figure out how you want the HTML to look and then figure out how ASP.NET MVC can help you generate the correct HTML.

Comment: I know html, and I know how to style tabs, it's just another nav bar, but you don't know how many tabs there are going to be, you have to be able to update that based on the number of entries in the database, and so I'm asking how you would update the number of tabs based on the number of records in a database and how you would figure out the number of records in the database, in the for each I'm using to generate the html, you can't track how many items get displayed because even if you increment a variable it goes out of scope when the foreach is over. Trust me I'm not a complete mess.

Comment: My advice still stands. First figure out how to do it in HTML. Then figure out how to do it with ASP.NET MVC. The question of  "how to do it in HTML" is actually much too broad for [so] since there are so many possible answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With tabs, you are dealing with a finite amount of data. For example, input forms on a screen with each tab that represents a different category. From a user's perspective, having an infinite number of tabs to go through is rather painful.

I'd recommend looking into pagination as @Rowan mentioned. Sounds like that's more of what you are looking for. You break the posts into "pages" that lets the user navigate through content.